# Парсинг GSON, если имя класса не совпадает с именем в JSON

Tags: java, gson

Как правильно реализовать это через gson.
Есть класс Shop, а есть json который выглядит так.
Чтобы сопоставить поля есть аннотация `@SerializedName`. А вот как сделать если имя класса не совпадает с именем объекта в JSON? Есть ли какие-либо аннотации. Или делать класс обертку Data?

```html
{
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    "departments": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: По идее имя класса не имеет значения. Значение имеет только имя поля в классе и аннотация на нём

Comment: Такого быть не должно, если такое случается то надо другой парсер.

Answer (score 1):

Имя класса не обязательно должно совпадать с именем объекта. На вашем примере:

```
{
  "data": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Должно соответствовать следующему классу

```
public class Root {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private Shop shop;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ну так я и написал что вариант с врапером понятен и так, а вот как без него сделать, видимо никак.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека GSON содержит мощнейший механизм кастомной сериализации/десериализации объектов - дженерик интерфейсы

```
public interface JsonSerializer<T> {
    JsonElement serialize(T var1, Type var2, JsonSerializationContext var3);
}
```

и

```
public interface JsonDeserializer<T> {
    T deserialize(JsonElement var1, Type var2, JsonDeserializationContext var3) throws JsonParseException;
}
```

Реализовав их и использовав при создании объекта `GSON` через билдер `GsonBuilder`, зарегистрировав адептор к типу класса;

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(UrClass.class, new UrClassAdapter()).create()
```

Вы получите очень гибкий инструмент для всевозможных трансформаций представления вашего класса: от свертки параметров до преобразования типов, в том числе и изменения имён полей класса.